# How can I get both of my result sets from two different Laravel Query Builders to display on the same page at the same time?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8, laravel-query-builder

I'm building a quiz app in Laravel. I have two tables of data that I want to retrieve from my `MySQL` database. These tables are called `questions` and `answers`. I also have two query builders for each of these tables. A `questions` query builder and an `answers` query builder.

I created the questions query builder before the answers query builder and managed to retrieve and display my data just fine with the help of Blade. The questions appeared fine with my styling. Soon after, I created my answers query builder to retrieve my answers table from the database. This worked, as my answers visibly appeared, except, everything else including my questions and background styling disappeared. What's left is a page with an answer and the default white background. This happens when I point the route resource methods in `web.php` to my `localhost:8000/questions` page. This is where I want everything to show.

Naturally, both of these query builder methods are in their own controller files. `QuestionsController.php` and `AnswersController.php` . I tried using just one controller file with one query builder to retrieve both the questions and answers from my database using `->join`. I found this to be confusing though, especially when combined with my pagination methods. I've also learned it's better practice to compartmentalize your controller files when you have multiple data sets. My guess is that there is something wrong with my Blade code as it's the styling that's being messed with.

**QuestionsController.php**

```
public function index() 
    {
        $questions = DB::table('questions')->simplePaginate(1);                            
        return view('questions.questions', ['questions' => $questions]); 
    }
```

**AnswersController.php**

```
public function index() 
    {
        $answers = DB::table('answers')->simplePaginate(1);                            
        return view('answers.answers', ['answers' => $answers]); 
    }
```

**questions.blade.php**

```
@extends('home')
@if(count($questions))
    @foreach($questions as $question)
        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-top: 200px; margin-left: 550px; position: absolute; z-index: 99;">
            <p>{{$question->question}}</p> 
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else 
    <p>How embarrassing. We couldn't even provide you a question. Worst quiz ever.</p> 
@endif 
// this is where my form goes
{{ $questions->links() }}
```

**answers.blade.php**

```
@if(count($answers))
    @foreach($answers as $answer)
        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-top: 200px; margin-left: 550px; position: absolute; z-index: 99;">
            <p>{{$answer->answer}}</p> 
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else 
    <p>How embarrassing. We couldn't even provide you any answers. Worst quiz ever.</p> 
@endif
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionsController');  
Route::resource('questions', 'AnswersController');
```

**The objective is to have both my questions and answers displayed on the same page**. With the styling intact.

P.S. I'm aware that I'm returning two different views, one in `QuestionsController.php` and the other in `AnswersController.php`. I understand that this is probably the route of the problem. I just don't know an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.php, does your answers controller resource need to be:

```
 Route::resource('answers', 'AnswersController');
```

rather than:

```
Route::resource('questions', 'AnswersController');
```

Comment: No, because I'm trying to get both the questions and answers on the questions page. Therefore, both routes should point to 'questions'. If I use 'answers' as the first argument, I would have two different pages for both the questions and answers which is not what I want.

Comment: In your answers table, do you have a question_id, or something similar, for the question the answer relates to?